# Is it possible to create sequence(?) data with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have the employee data like this:

| ID | previous_org | new_org | event | event_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | A | Hire | 202201 |
| 1 | A | B | Transfer | 202207 |
| 1 |  | B | Retired | 202301 |
| 2 |  | A | Hire | 202201 |
| 2 | A | B | Transfer | 202207 |
| 2 | B | C | Transfer | 202301 |
| 2 |  | C | Retired | 202308 |

I want to add two columns to above data and manage it as historical data.

The columns I want to add are `start_date` and `end_date`.

It is difficult to explain what I want to do, so I will show the desired result below.

| ID | previous_org | new_org | event | event_date | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | A | Hire | 202201 | 202201 | 202206 |
| 1 | A | B | Transfer | 202207 | 202207 | 202212 |
| 1 |  | B | Retired | 202301 | 202301 |  |
| 2 |  | A | Hire | 202201 | 202201 | 202206 |
| 2 | A | B | Transfer | 202207 | 202207 | 202212 |
| 2 | B | C | Transfer | 202301 | 202301 | 202307 |
| 2 |  | C | Retired | 202308 | 202308 |  |

The `start_date` column contains the date in the `event_date` column of the row.

The `end_date` column contains the date one month before the date in the `event_date` column for the next event.

Calculations must be made for each employee.

Can I get this result with SQL Server?

I understand that this can be accomplished using something other than SQL Server, but in this case I must use SQL Server.

Any answer would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use LEAD function to get the next startdate and then remove one month from it

Comment: Perhaps change the name to "StartMonth" and "EndMonth" since that is all the granularity your data allows currently.   What have you tired here and how can we help you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

**Code**:

```
with cte as(
SELECT 
    ID, previous_org, new_org, event, event_date, startdate=event_date,
    Lead(event_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY event_date) as ed
  FROM employee)
select ID, previous_org, new_org, event, event_date, startdate,
  format(dateadd(month,-1,cast(iif(ed is not null,concat(ed,'01'),null) as date)),'yyyyMM') as enddate from cte
```

This code uses a `CTE`  to derive the  `ed` column (temporary column) as the next `event_date` using the `LEAD` function. Then, it calculates the `enddate` column by concatenating the `ed` column with `'01'` to get the complete date format `yyyyMMdd`, and then it is casted to a `date` data type. Then  `DATEADD`- is used to substract one month from the derived value. Later, it formats as a string in the `'yyyyMM'` format using the `FORMAT` function.

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BQYLkQ96)

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer. I tried this and it worked well. Thank you so much.